# Change Label.Text based on the current time?

Tags: c#, winforms

How might I be able to change the Text property of a label depending on what the current time is?

Thank you

To clarify:

I'd like the text of a label to read open between 10am and 5pm and then read closed between 5:01 pm to 9:59am.

Comment: Uhm, check the time, and if it looks like what you want, change the label.text property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display updated time as system time on a label using c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025840/how-to-display-updated-time-as-system-time-on-a-label-using-c)

Comment: @KP No that is not what I'm asking..

Comment: @crm - Actually it is.  Just modify the code to check what the current time is within a timer that runs once every minute.

Comment: @crm yes I see that now - you've completely changed the context of your question through edits.

Comment: er no I just added the bit at the bottom to clarify to people that didnt understand,,

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).  In the Timer.Tick handler, modify the label's Text property using a simple if/else statement based on DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 3):

```
int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;

if (hour >= 10 && hour < 17) 
    //Open 10:00am through 4:59pm
    LabelStatus.Text = "Open";
else
    //Closed 5:00pm through 9:59am
    LabelStatus.Text = "Closed";
```

Comment: You need to go into greater detail of how to use this code.  This does not do what the author wants.  He wants the sign to read open at 5PM not 4:59PM there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a method to do this using a separate thread that updates the label. This way the thread will run in the background, and constantly check that the label is at the correct status. Make sure when closing the form you stop the thread, either by using Thread.Abort() and catching the exception that I believe is always thrown, or by adding a flag as the condition in the while loop, and lower the flag to stop the thread.

As long as no other object accesses the label, there shouldn't be any need to lock any part of the thread.

```
    public delegate void DelLabelText(Label l, string s);
    public DelLabelText delLabelText;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        delLabelText = Label_Text;

        // Initialize text
        lblOpenStatus.Text = "Closed";

        // Create and start thread
        Thread threadUpdateLabel = new Thread(UpdateLabel_Threaded);
        threadUpdateLabel.Start();
    }

    // Thread function that constantly checks if the text is correct
    public void UpdateLabel_Threaded()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            // 24 hour clock so 17 means 5
            if ((DateTime.Now.Hour >= 10 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 17) || (DateTime.Now.Hour == 17 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0 && DateTime.Now.Second == 0))
            {
                if (lblOpenStatus.Text.ToLower() == "closed")
                {
                    Label_Text(lblOpenStatus, "Open");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (lblOpenStatus.Text.ToLower() == "open")
                {
                    Label_Text(lblOpenStatus, "Closed");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the text using invoke, because text is changed outside of main thread
    public void Label_Text(Label label, string text)
    {
        if (label.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label.Invoke(delLabelText, new object[] { label, text });
        }
        else
        {
            label.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lots of work went into this answer, but it really clocks the processor with the while(true) and is a bear to program.  A simple Timer object here that runs every 1000 milliseconds and checks the current time should suffice.

Comment: Added a Thread.Sleep, but after reading your comment I do agree that timer might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer to your form and set its interval to 1000 ms..

Declare a invisible TextBox having the Miliseconds of the current time updated by the Timer on Every Tick..

now on the TextBox.TextChanged event of the Textbox Add a Function to Convert the Milliseconds to Time...

Next Method is add a Timer and set the interval to 1 ms...

Update the time from there..

Next Method, is adding a BackgroundWorker and use it as a Timer to update the Time...

If you find any of the above methods useful...Comment and I will post codes! :)

Comment: This answer needs some work, the thought process is all over the place, code would make it even better.

Comment: @Ramhound The [Answer Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10541756/1118933) tells Everything but if the Thread is Replaced with Timer ,It will work better.