# current time in Console C# but continuously change as system time change

Tags: c#, date, console-application

As in this thread: [How to display updated time as system time on a label using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025840/how-to-display-updated-time-as-system-time-on-a-label-using-c)

I want the same solution in Console apps...
Datetime class just show the current time of system but it doesn't changed as system time change.
Is it possible?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what exactly you're asking. In normal console applications once your write something to the console, it stays that way.

Comment: no i wanted the time changing as system time is changing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to clear console and write new content to console.

```
while(true)
{

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(DeteTime.Now);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
```

Comment: little upvote wouldn't harm :)

Comment: "DeteTime.Now" you have a typo there, it is "DateTime.Now"